# How to reset a react-native animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've made some simple animation using `Animated` from [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated)
The animation works as expected after the first onPress, but I can't figure out how to reset it, to make it work for the next taps.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.spinValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    // Second interpolate beginning and end values (in this case 0 and 1)
    this.spin = this.spinValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        outputRange: ['0deg', '4deg', '0deg', '-4deg', '0deg']
    });
}

handlePress() {
    // First set up animation 
    Animated.timing(
        this.spinValue,
        {
            toValue: 4,
            duration: 300,
        }
    ).start();
}
```

And in render

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { this.handlePress(); }} >
                    <Animated.Image
                        source={someImg}
                        style={{ height: undefined, width: undefined, flex: 1, transform: [{ rotate: this.spin }, { perspective: 1000 }] }}
                        resizeMode={'contain'}
                        resizeMethod="resize"
                    />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `this.spinValue.setValue(0)` to reset it. You can add it at the beginning of `handlePress`.

Comment: I can't seem to find `setValue` in the latest API anymore. Is this method deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a single animated value, `this.spinValue.setValue(0)` will do the job, as Antoine mentioned in his comment. In case of a more complex sequence using [reset()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#reset) from the Animated API.

Here is a simple example with only 2 animation refs:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

const animationFn = ({ opacity, offset }) => {
  return Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(opacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      duration: 200,
    }),
    Animated.timing(offset, {
      toValue: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      duration: 500,
    }),
  ]);
};

const App = () => {
  const opacity = useRef(Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const offset = useRef(Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const animation = useRef(animationFn({ opacity, offset })).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const animationEnd = {
      // it resets all the initial values, in our case opacity and offset 
      // to initial values before the animation started
      animation.reset(); 
    };

    animation.start(animationEnd);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View styles={[viewStyles, { opacity, transform: [{ translateX: offset }] }]} />
  );
}
```

Did not test this particular snippet but this should give you an idea on how `animation.reset()` works. `animation.reset()` could be called on animation end, onPress, in the component cleanup phase, etc.

Answer (score -3):

you can use `Aminated.reset()` method.